# how to search and get value mulit dxn array using key or value in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

am using codeigniter

I have the following array mulitdxnal ;

```
$config['categories'] = array(
  'HL'=>array(
        'Bath & Beauty',
        'Musical Instruments',
       ),

    'MA'=>array(
        'Decals',
        'Docking Stations & Chargers'=>array('choice1','choice2'),
     ) 
);
```

All i want is i want to cascade a drop down box for categories in **MA** and find it elements then when elements selected populate its sub elements like

```
 'Docking Stations & Chargers'=>array('choice1','choice2'); //c1,c2
```

will be populated.

so how could i search and return values by using value of this array.

Thankyou~~!~

Answer (score 0):

use `is_array()` to check if the value has an array or not in your loop. Take a look on simple example:

```
$categories = array(
 'HL'=>array(
    'Bath & Beauty',
    'Musical Instruments',
   ),

  'MA'=>array(
    'Decals',
    'Docking Stations & Chargers'=>array('choice1','choice2'),
   ) 
);

foreach( $categories as $key => $category ) {
    if( $key == "MA" ) {
        foreach( $category as $_k => $sub_category ) {

            // Check of Sub Category is array and holds values
            if( is_array( $sub_category ) && count($sub_category) > 0 ) {
                // Sub-Category Loop here
            }
            else {
               // Normal Value of Sub Category
            }
        }
    }
}
```